# Handling of arbitrary options using Tornado options, i.e. like **kwargs

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado, keyword-argument

I'm using `Tornado options` to define command-line arguments. However, I would like to be able to throw arbitrary configuration options, not defined in code, to my program. These will differ, depending on what the program is supposed to do. For instance, connect to a bluetooth device using a MAC address or connect to a serial device using a TTY.

If I define a set of "mandatory" options in code and then add an additional when calling the program, I get an exception thrown by `parse_command_line()`.

It would be very handy to get e.g. a dictionary with the remaining (undefined) options. That is, much in the same way as `**kwargs` works in functions.

Can this be done?

(A work-around is to define a string option named e.g. configuration and throw everything in there, possibly encoded in some clever way. As the program is being called by another program I can e.g. base64-encode a serialized dict.)

---

**Update:** I've noticed that if you add command-line args without leading dashes, Tornado will ignore them and return a list with remaining (undefined) options.

Comment: Have you tried using argparse?

Comment: Sounds messy. Why not have one mandatory parameter that then determines the viable options and can dispatch to something to handle them appropriately. Otherwise it sounds like you're opening it up for people to mix'n'match varying/possibly conflicting options...

Comment: @Jon Clements: A mandatory parameter that sets viable options is a pretty neat idea. As long as all options have been defined when parse_command_line() is called it will work. In addition, I think it will even reflect on the help message provided when a required argument is unfilled.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Yes, but not in this project. Tornado is a requirement here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create subclass of `OptionParser` singleton and modify parsing method. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

from tornado.options import OptionParser
import sys

class MyOptionParser(OptionParser):
    def parse_command_line(self, args=None, final=True):
        if args is None:
            args = sys.argv
        remaining = []
        for i in range(1, len(args)):
            # All things after the last option are command line arguments
            if not args[i].startswith("-"):
                remaining = args[i:]
                break
            if args[i] == "--":
                remaining = args[i + 1:]
                break
            arg = args[i].lstrip("-")
            name, equals, value = arg.partition("=")
            name = name.replace('-', '_')
            if not name in self._options:
#   modified line       self.print_help()
#   modified line       raise Error('Unrecognized command line option: %r' % name)
                self.define(name, help="Arbitrary option") # new line
            option = self._options[name]
            if not equals:
                if option.type == bool:
                    value = "true"
                else:
                    raise Error('Option %r requires a value' % name)
            option.parse(value)

        if final:
            self.run_parse_callbacks()

        return remaining

options = MyOptionParser()
options.define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write(options.myoption) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/", IndexHandler)])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The only difference from [source](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/options.html#OptionParser.parse_command_line) is I'm defining passed option instead of throwing an Exception. Running:

```
python test.py --myoption="test"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `tornado.options` philosophy is that *any* module may define options, not just the main entry point.  So if you might need a bluetooth mac address, you'd define that option in the module that interacts with bluetooth.  (and if you might need more than one you can set `multiple=True`).  The only tricky part is that you must import all modules that define options before calling `parse_command_line`.  Truly arbitrary options are not supported by tornado.options.

It's also possible to use argparse or another command-line library instead of `tornado.options.parse_command_line` - the rest of tornado doesn't care whether you're using `tornado.options` or not.